# Как правильно записать различные строки данных в одно поле?

Tags: php, mysql, get, статистика

На веб-сайте планируется сделать отслеживание входящего трафика. То есть PHP скрипт должен принимать GET параметры входящего трафика и записывать в БД. К примеру ссылка
https://example.com/?utm_source=youtube&utm_medium=video&utm_campaign=Cool_boy&utm_content=pre-roll
будет разобрана на:
1)youtube
2)video
3)Cool_boy
4)pre-roll
Далее эти значения должны быть записаны в одно поле таблицы БД. Делать отдельные поля под каждое значение неудачное решение, так как параметров может быть больше или меньше по количеству, поэтому запись в одно поле. Вопрос, как в строковое поле записать эти параметры, записывать все в JSON чтоб потом удобно статистику на PHP выводить, или использовать пробел или может какой-нибудь специальный символ, как лучше и почему?

Comment: *Делать отдельные поля под каждое значение неудачное решение, так как параметров может быть больше или меньше по количеству, поэтому запись в одно поле.* Вот это Вы сейчас глупость сказали. Наоборот, объединение в одном поле нескольких значений - типичный bad practice. А в данном конкретном случае это относится и к JSON-формату.

Comment: @Akina , да с точки зрения структуры это глупость, но с точки зрения экономии памяти, по моему единственный способ, предположим есть 100 000 пользователей и только 500 из них имеют все 4 параметра, а остальные только по одному, выходит будет 99 500 строк в таблице где 3 из 4 значений будет пустыми или NULL, разве не стоит избегать такого расхода памяти?

Comment: Сто тысяч строк... максимум 4 NULL (признак NULL в MySQL занимает 1 байт)... четыреста килобайт...  да, конечно, ТАКОЙ расход памяти - причина серьёзно озаботиться...

Comment: @Akina , воу, воу, можно и без сарказма, в остальном понял, решение наиболее правильное.

Comment: *можно и без сарказма* Да куда ж без него-то? Или Вы думаете, что достаточно говорить правильные слова? не-е-е, к ним ещё обязательно надо приложить материальный баланс, иначе они так словами и останутся. А если всё это приправить сарказмом, то оно лучше запомнится. А пока - загляните в мануалы (не MySQL, а вообще, идеологически) и посмотрите, что они там думают про sparse table.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы потом планируете использовать эти данные в других приложениях(например вы разрабатываете api и хотите получить эти данные через js), то однозначно лучше использовать json, т.к он дает стандартизацию данных. Это можно сказать хорошая практика стандартизировать хранение данных в один вид, то JSON для этого прекрасно подходит. Если вам принципиально нужно разделять через пробел и никак больше, то используйте этот способ, но все зависит, как вы будете использовать эти данные в будущем. Потому-что например если у вас будут массивы в query параметрах, то сохранять в виде строки будет не удобно, т.к это все потом придется разбирать, что будет крайне не удобно делать. JSON эту проблему решит и вне зависимости от усложнения структуры всегда можно будет легко распарсить в массив через json_decode
В mysql 5.7.8 был введен тип данных JSON https://phptoday.ru/post/ispolzovanie-json-v-mysql
Переводите query параметры в массив, например через parse_str, кодируете его в json через json_encode и записываете полученную строку в столбец, который имеет тип данных JSON.